# Why does the text prepended by jquery appear for a split second, then suddenly disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple html file where I can add pastes and store them temporarily. I have a text form with a submit button, that is supposed to prepend the value of the form to the div "#pastes", but when I use jquery to do this, the text is prepended for a split second, then disappears! Something also seems to quickly flash in the Inspect Element section, but it disappears too quickly and I can't see it. Also, the file I am linking to from my computer changes its name from `file:///Users/homework/Documents/pastebook/pastebook.html` to `file:///Users/homework/Documents/pastebook/pastebook.html?pasteinput=asdf` after the input ("asdf" being the input of the paste.)

EDIT: My bad, I meant append to the div, not prepend.

EDIT: I can't use inline javascript because I want to make this a Chrome Extension

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="pastebook.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="pastebook.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <form id="pasteform">
                <div id="input"><input type="text" name="pasteinput"></div>
                <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="pastes">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pasteform").submit(function() {
        $("#pastes").append( $("input:first" ).val());
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 250px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F8E0;
}
```

### Edit based on comments

I [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9M65/) and changed my JS to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("#button").click(function() {             
        $("#pastes").append( $("input:first" ).val());         
   });     
});
```

Comment: What you think `input type="submit"` does?

Comment: because you are submitting the form... which is reloading the form causing it to reset

Comment: You are submitting a form at the same time you are appending input text. After submitting it reload the page... so how will you get append input text as it will show original page

Comment: Oh! How would I be able to append the value of the text box without reloading the page then?

Comment: but why do you want to append text while submitting? ... what is your exactrequirement?

Comment: @BitLion That's just the magic in `append`, it appends content without reload ; ). Just use `onclick` and `input type="button"`.

Comment: I didn't know submitting the form reloaded the page; I just want the value of the text box to append to my div

Comment: If you don't want to submit a form, why do you even have one?

Comment: Then do the same action on some other button but not on submit button. Take simple input with type="button" and call the same code to append text..it will work

Comment: I changed my JS to this: 
    `$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $("#pastes").append( $("input:first" ).val());
        });
    });`
and added a Button under the text box but it still is not working

Comment: please share JSfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9M65/

Comment: You've forgotten `type="button"`, Default action of `button` in form is to submit the form. [A forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHFzm/) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see updated code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9M65/12/). I have updated button tag to input tag and it worked.

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Paste!"></input>
```

or you can just put type="button" in button tag like below

```
<button type="button" id="button">Paste!</button>
```

because button tag submit page by default

Comment: [Should we flag “look at my answer” comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253833/should-we-flag-look-at-my-answer-comments?cb=1).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, submitting the form will reload the page, so your appended input gets lost. Just change your HTML:

```
<body>
     <div id="form">
          <input type="text" name="pasteinput">
          <button type="button" onclick="appendInput()">Append</button> 
     </div>
     <div id="pastes">

     </div>
</body>
```

And jQuery:

```
function appendInput() {
        $("#pastes").append( $("input:first" ).val());
}
```

Your page won't reload now and your Input gets appended properly.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, forgot to mention; I don't want to use inline JS because I want to make this a Chrome Extension; manifest 2.0 doesn't allow inline js.

Comment: You can just change your jQuery to `$("button").click(function() { $("#pastes").append( $("input:first" ).val()); });` and delete the onclick in HTML then :)